# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'null'. Please specify one with --class

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-submit

While trying to up the service using `spark-submit`, I am getting this Error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get main class in JAR with error 'null'.  Please specify one with --class.
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.error(SparkSubmit.scala:968)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:486)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

tried Spark submit command